# развёртывание БД в postgres

Tags: postgresql

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: есть файл demo.sql, создающий и разворачивающий базу данных demo, не могу найти где должен находиться файл demo.sql, что бы создать и развернуть базу командой psql `-f demo_small.sql -U postgres`? Или может надо что-то добавить? При том что команда `\i путь_к_файлу/demo_small.sql` всё отлично накатывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где угодно на той машине, откуда запускается `psql`.

`psql` - это клиент к PostgreSQL, аргумент `-f` ожидает получить путь до файла в файловой системе той машины, где запущен `psql`. Это может быть просто имя файла и тогда `psql` будет его искать в той директории, где вы находились при вызове `psql`. Это может быть относительный путь, это может быть абсолютный путь.

Если вы можете сделать `ls путь_до_файла` - этот же самый путь сгодится для `psql`

Команда `\i` внутри `psql` имеет ровно тот же самый смысл, ожидает получить путь к файлу на той системе, где запущен `psql` (но не где запущен postgresql, если это разные устройства)